# Can't post question, error message not showing

Tags: bug, asking-questions, self-answer, quality-filter

I selected answer my own quesiton, and then after filing out subject, question, and answer,

- tried to post
- got an error about missing tag.
- I added a tag and then tried to post again, and the page just refreshes but **there are no errors**.  The URL changed to https://serverfault.com/questions/ask/submit
- I have tried completely refreshing the page, but still cannot post, but get no errors.
- If I remove the answer your own question option(which behaves strangely as the checkbox then disappears so that I can't re-enable it),

  - **I then see errors indicating the the question does not meet quality standards.**

So it seems there is a client side issue with at least this particular error not being displayed if you have also chosen "answer your own post".  I'm sure I will get the classic "Well if it hurts when you do that, then don't do that" response, but oh well I tried.

This is in latest Chrome on Windows 7.  No anti-javascript plugins activated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You definitely should be notified that the question doesn't meet quality standards even when you choose to answer your own question at the same time.